# How can I recursively build a list inside another list in F#?

Tags: list, recursion, f#

I have an int list as input

```
[1;2;3;4]
```

and I need to output a list containing this list

```
[[1;2;3;4]]
```

I need to do it recursively because I have to filter some values.

Basically, I need (and can't seem to sort it out) to start from here:

```
[[2]]
```

and achieve this:

```
[[1;2]]
```

Comment: how is this realated (wrapping into the list and filtering) - because from right now it looks like `yourList |> List.filter yourPredicate |> List.singleton` is all you need and I just cannot see how you would want to do this recursively (do you want to wrap/unwrap all the time?)

Comment: In what way does it need to be recursive? What would be the terminating condition of the recursion?

Comment: Terminating condition would be [] -> [] and [x] -> [[x]]

Comment: This is what I came up with: `match l with
    [] -> []
    |[x] -> [[x]]
    |x::xs -> split_eq ( x::xs ) ` but generates a list of singletons

Comment: I think I'm failing my MENSA test right now, but how can `[1;2;3;4]` become `[[1;2;3;4]]` while `[[2]]` becomes `[[1;2]]`? I don't see the pattern... or perhaps I see too many?

Comment: well MENSA... let's see what about `List.max >> (fun m -> [[1..m]])`? :D

Comment: Like Mark said, I think people are struggling to provide an answer to this because they can't see how [[2]] becomes [[1;2]]. It doesn't appear to just be a problem about wrapping a list of values in another list. Are we missing some other information here?

Answer (score 0):

You can first filter your list and then enclose filtered result it in the outer list:

```
let source = [1; 2; 3; 4]
let filtered = List.filter (fn x -> x % 2 = 0) src
let result = [filtered]
```